# Can't POST with Twitter API

Tags: python, twitter

When I run my Twitter bot, I keep getting 400 errors.

I've checked that I'm using APIv1.1 and that I'm under my rate limit:

```
x-ratelimit-class: api
x-ratelimit-limit: 150
x-ratelimit-remaining: 148
x-ratelimit-reset: 1365882051
x-transaction: a561da7695963295
```

I don't know if my url is incorrect or not. I've tried formatting it differently but still get the same error. I've tried all 3 of these formats:

```
    data = None
    full_url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/retweet/"  + tweet + ".json"
    response = urllib2.urlopen(full_url, data)

    response = urllib2.urlopen("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/retweet/%s.json" % tweet, data)
    response = urllib2.urlopen("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/retweet/{}.json".format(tweet), data)
```

`Tweet` is a string for sure.

This call is the second one in my program. The first API call updates my own status based on a condition, so it rarely does actually do the tweet action. Could that be a problem? This API call is also in a for loop - could that be a problem?

Comment: According to [docs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/error-codes-responses), you're sending requests without authentication. Please, try to make post request with [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/). Hope that helps.

Comment: For post you need to authenticate. and set the rights for the application to "Read+Write" at https://dev.twitter.com/apps/new